# Spring Cloud Stream RabbitMQ multiple receivers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I am having trouble grasping the knowledge of how RabbitMQ and Spring Cloud Stream work together. What i want to do is the following (Basic explanation):

I have a producer which produces messages, which are things like: SendEmail, ReceiveEmail and ErrorOccurred. These will go on the message bus.
Then i have 3 consumers. A `LogService` an `Emailservice` and a `ParserService`.

`EmailService` will pick up all the `Email` messages, `LogService` will pick up the `ErrorOccurred` (generated by other producers too) and the `EmailSend` messages. Finally the `ParserService` will only get the `ReceiveEmail` messages.

I cant seem to get this configured with Spring Cloud Stream. I can send and receive a single event from one producer to one receiver, and one producer to multiple subscribers (one topic, multiple queue's but no wildcards).

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    username: guest
    password: guest
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output: # <-- Question 1
          destination: # <-- Question 2
```

With the standard `Source.class` interface binding.

And `EmailService`:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    username: guest
    password: guest
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: # <-- Question 3
```

And the same for `LogService` as the above.

Question 1: I only defined one output, but obviously i need 2? But then i cant use "input"  as channel name right? And i need to configure my own Channel names with `Output("CHANNEL NAME HERE")`. But what does this channel name mean? I dont see the channel name reappearing in the RabbitMQ webinterface or anything. Is this just application internal naming?

Question 2: This is the exchange name as far as i understood. If i read the docs right, i need an Topic type exchange for the `Email` messages as i have 3 receivers. Do i also have 3 separate queues then? But how do i configure 1 queue receives only `EmailReceived`, 1 queue receiving all and 1 queue the `EmailSend` messages?

Question 3: Do i need to make an exchange for every different event i want to send? Shouldn't i be able to subscribe to all `email.*` events? If i use it like that, i create a queue with that exact name and a Topic with that exact name. Which is not right, as far as i know.

I want to do it liek this, https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-spring-amqp.html. But the problem is, they use the basic RabbitMQ Spring AMQP and i chose to use the Spring Cloud Stream (as it is advertised as THE tool to make microservice communication atc etc).

Should i use SCS or should i use Spring-AMQP library? if so, how should i configure this? If i need to explain more, please ask for any clarification. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

On the producer side, you only need one destination; set the `routingKeyExpression` to route to one of 3 queues, based on something in the message (e.g. a header - `routing-key-expression=headers[route]`).

You can also have multiple output channels pointing to the same destination (but with a different - literal - routing key expression `'email.foo'`).

On the consumer side; you can use the same destination, but each consumer will have one queue bound to that exchange, side the `bindingRoutingKey` to, e.g., `email.#`.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbitmq_binder).

Comment: Thanks, i will try this out today. I will keep you updated

Comment: @garyrussell On the consumer side; is it possible to have a configuration for binding several exchanges to a single queue?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers. Ask a new question with more details. The simple answer is yes; but you need to provide more context. Exchanges are not bound to queues; queues are bound to exchanges.